# How to use the PI constant in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I imported [math](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-math/dart-math-library.html).

```
import 'dart:math';
```

But how can I call "PI" constant?

This is not working.

```
   math.pi / 12.0
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

you should 
`import 'dart:math' as math;` instead of just `import 'dart:math';`

because when you use the `as` keyword you provide the imported library a name so you can reference it anywhere in your file

Answer (score 28):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, you can keep importing without a prefix, and reference `pi` as just `pi`:

```
import "dart:math" show pi;
main() {
  print(pi / 12);
}
```

This works just as well as prefixing. It's a matter of taste which one you prefer.

Answer (score 13):

First   `import 'dart:math';` 
then use `pi/12.0` instead of `math.PI/12.0` it should work fine.